# Automated testing of Episerver editor functionality

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, imacros, episerver

Anyone succeeded in automated testing Episerver with Imacros or Selenium?
I tried, recording with Imacros and Selenium but did'nt manage to play back due to the fact that Episerver generates dynamic ID's for elements (each run they have a different ID)
Excuse me if my question is to vague but it's hard to describe and be more specific.

Comment: Among the iMacros Recording options there is a check-box to use element ids whenever possible. Try to uncheck it and record the macro once again.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.